# OpenCV loading and displaying video produce inaccurate colours

Tags: opencv

I was following the example given in the OpenCV for video displaying, just took out some transformations unnecessary for me. The code I have right now loads the video file and then displays it, the problem is that reproduced video have wrong colours.

Here's the code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// The main function

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

VideoCapture cap ("ETMI 002.mpg");  // Open the file

if (!cap.isOpened ())               // Check if opening was successful
    cerr << "I have failed!" << endl;

else
{
    Mat edges;
    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    while (cap.read (frame))
    {
      cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2RGB);  
      imshow("edges", edges);
      if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Did you try to display the frame directly, without BGR2RGB? imshow takes as input BGR images, and only if you have a RGB image you should convert it to BGR before imshow().

Comment: `imshow()` take BGR imags, try it without `cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2RGB);  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid transformation in reproduced video change
*imshow("edges", `edges`)*  to
*imshow("edges", `frame`)*

```
while (cap.read (frame))
{
  cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2RGB); 

  // here is the change you are showing the converted image 
  // just simply add the original read frame

  imshow("edges", frame);   // here 
  if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
```